# INSERT only if at least one column is unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

Consider that, I have the following values in a table.

| Name | Contact Number | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 | L1 |
| XYZ | 456 | L2 |

Now, the following set of insert should work

```
ABC, 123, L2
ABC, 456, L3
ABC, 789, L1
MNO, 567, L5
```

But, following set should not insert.

```
ABC, 123, L1
XYZ, 456, L2
```

The concatenated string of columns of each row should be unique.

Can someone please help to build the SQL query?

Comment: Have you had a look at a `UNIQUE` `CHECK` `CONSTRAINT`?

Comment: Do you want to ensure that "at least one column is unique", which is what your title says, or do you want to ensure that "the concatenated string of columns" is unique, which is what the body of your question says? These are *not* the same! If the latter, can any of the columns be `null`?

Comment: The concatenated string of columns of each row should be unique. any column can be NULL

Comment: So the 2 rows `'abl',2,NULL` and `'ab',NULL,'l2'` should generate an error then, @John .

Comment: When you start trying to do things like make unique indexes across rows it is very clear sign that the design of your data structure is less than ideal. You probably need to take a step back and examine your data structure and what you are trying to store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you confirmed that you want the concatenation to be unique, a trivial unique constraint like this will not work:

```sql
alter table MyTable
add constraint MyUniqueConstraintName 
unique ([Name], [Contact Number], [Location]);
```

Because that would allow the following insert, contrary to your requirement:

```sql
insert T ([Name], [Contact Number], [Location])
values ('abc', 'de', 'f'),
       ('a', 'bc', 'def');
```

What we can do is add a computed column, and then force the computed column to be unique:

```sql
alter table T add 
   Concatenated as concat([Name], [Contact Number], [Location]),
   constraint ConcatenatedValueMustBeUnique unique (Concatenated);
```

However, one additional wrinkle is that you said that any of the columns can be `null`. This raises two awkward questions

1. Does `null` equal `null`, for the purposes of your requirement?
2. Does "" equal `null` for the purposes of your requirement?

Here's an example of each:

```sql
-- should this be allowed or disallowed?
insert T ([Name], [Contact Number], [Location])
values ('ab', null, 'cd'),
       ('ab', '', 'cd');

-- what about this? 
insert T ([Name], [Contact Number], [Location])
values ('ab', null, 'cd'),
       ('ab', null, 'cd');
```

In the strictest case (that is to say, the case of the most restrictive constraint), we would say "`null` equals `null`, and `null` also equals the empty string", which you could express as

```sql
alter table T add 
   Concatenated as concat
   (
      isnull([Name], ''),
      isnull([Contact Number], ''),
      isnull([Location], '')
   ),
   constraint UniqueConcat unique (Concatenated);
```

But that is actually equivalent to the original constraint I provided, because `concat` "eliminates" `null` (turns it into an empty string), so it's the same as `Concatenated as concat([Name], [Contact Number], [Location])`

If you require the condition "`null` equals `null` but `null` does not equal the empty string", you might replace the empty string in the `isnull` expressions above with something like `char(0)`.

But if you want to say "`null` does not equal `null`", things actually get rather tricky. So hopefully you don't want to say that!

If you want to do it as code rather than a constraint - I wouldn't recommend it, because what if someone writes data into the table using different code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `EXCEPT` operator:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (Name,[Contact Number],[Location])
SELECT Name,[Contact Number],[Location]
FROM (  VALUES  ('ABC','123','L1') 
        ) as xyz(Name,[Contact Number],[Location])
EXCEPT 
SELECT Name,[Contact Number],[Location]
FROM dbo.MyTable;
```